# On the meaning of the Born series written as geometric series

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

I'm reading about the Born series and the Lippmann–Schwinger equation and I have a problem with the concept of formal solution.

The Born series reads

$|\psi> = |\phi> + G_0 V|\phi> + [G_0 V]^2|\phi> + [G_0 V]^3|\phi>...= [I-G_0V]^{-1}|\phi>.$

where $|\phi>$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation, $G_0$ is the Green's function and $V$ is the potential. Now the right side is the usual geometric series and in some places, it is called a formal solution.
What does mean formal solution in this contest?

Also, does the above equation means that in the coordinate base and for a multiplicative potential V(x) we have

$\psi(x)=\phi(x)+\int \frac{\phi(x^{'})}{I-G_0(x,x^{'})V(x^{'})} dx^{'} $

If yes, why I cannot find such an expression in any book?

Comment: Because the $^{-1}$ indicates here the inverse in operatorial sense and not in algebraic sense as you wrote in the integral...

Comment: Yes, I agree that I abused a bit the notation. Anyway, let assume that the potential is just the operator multiplication. Is the equation right?

Comment: No, it is not because $G$ is not local.

Comment: Please, can you elaborate a bit more? G_0 is a spherical wave in this case. Do you mean that being G_0 a function of |x-x'| gives problems?

Comment: The powers $(G_0V)^n$ have to be understood in the sense of the composition of operators. This coincides with the standard product of $n$ factors only if $G_0V$ is multiplicative (local), otherwise each factor is a convolution...

Comment: You are right, it's clear, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!